# error:0409A06E:rsa routines data too large for key size

Tags: node.js, cryptography, saml

I'm generating a SAML response and it needs to be encrypted and signed with public and private keys. I generated `private.pem` and `public.pem` in the terminal with the commands

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in ./private.pem -pubout -out public.pem
```

Then in nodeJS.

```
encrypt: function(message) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var publicKey = require("fs").readFileSync(__dirname + "/public.pem", "utf8");
        var encrypted = require("crypto").publicEncrypt(publicKey, new Buffer(message));
        resolve(encrypted.toString("base64"));
    });
},
```

Once I call the message `encrypt(xml)`, I get the following error

```
{
  library: 'rsa routines',
  function: 'RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1',
  reason: 'data too large for key size',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_RSA_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE'
}
```

**Objective**:

I've to sign the message as per the demo here [samltools.com](https://www.samltool.com/sign_response.php) (*Mode: SignMessage*), my SAML message looks like [this](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php). (*see SAML Response section*).

1. Sign the message
2. Base64Encode the message

Comment: What you want to do remains unclear. Your demo link only talks about signing, not encryption. Yet you have "Encrypt the message" as your first objective.

Comment: sorry, sign the message, now that I've learned more about it, it's signing, I'll remove the encrypt part

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you cannot directly encrypted with `RSA`, a piece of data which is larger than the key size.

Surprising I know, it surprised me too.

In reality very little payload data is encrypted directly with RSA or even elliptic curves.

You should be using RSA Diffie-Hellman to generate a shared secret.

Signature of the file, is really signature of the hash of the file.

Comment: Can I please get some help with code, I know very little about crypto